# Search in ListView atr Android

Tags: android

My code for search with TextChangedListener does't work. I nothing changes in ListView can u say me where is my problem?  I read it in this article http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/ and in other materials also I tryed

```
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    list.setFilterText(s.toString());
```

but it was't work too

```
code:

   public class SicksListActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher{
private DBHelper dbHelper;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sickness_list); 
    displaySicks();
}
private void displaySicks(){
    Queries queries=new Queries();
    Cursor c=queries.getAllSicks(this);
    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    EditText inputText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sick_input_search);
    inputText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    String [] colums={SicknessDB.NAME};
    int [] views={android.R.id.text1};
    adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, c, colums,views);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i didn't implement as you are implementing but i've done this multiple times and it works Perfect :

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int before,int count)   //Filter Data When Entering Data On EditText
        {
            Cursor FilteredListCursor = YourDBAdapter.instance.CursorFilteredData(s.toString());    //Retrieve Filtered Cursor
            ZoneCardListadapter.changeCursor(FilteredListCursor);

        }
```

Comment: my adapter is SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: it doesn't have instance.CursorFilteredData(s.toString())

Comment: nooo CursorFilteredData is a function that i give changed string from textwatcher to my Database Helper to filter my Cursor,its a simple custom function with a query with where clause with s String,you should implement it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
list.invalidateViews();
this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after

```
this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
```

Assuming `this.adapter` is your visible `ListView`'s actual adapter.